# SQL Server Creating Output table with Ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, range

I have the below query:

```
select a.ID, a.Date_Reported AS [Date Sent to X],  b.Date_Received AS [Date Returned from X], 

(datediff(dd, a.date_reported, b.date_received) 
      + CASE WHEN Datepart(dw, b.date_received) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
       - (Datediff(wk, a.date_reported, b.date_received) * 2 ) 
       - CASE WHEN Datepart(dw, b.date_received) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       - CASE WHEN Datepart(dw, b.date_received) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
       END) AS [Time_Spent]

from Tx_Ex a 
join Tx b on b.id = a.id
```

Simply, what the query does is the find the difference in working days between two dates (Date received - Date Reported) in two tables.

I want to adjust the query so my output looks like the below:

```
Time Taken (days) | 0-3 | 4 | 5 | 6-8 | 9+ | less than 0 days
Count             |  2  | 1 | 2 | 1   | 1  | 3
%                 | 20  | 10| 20| 10  | 10 | 30
```

So basically, I just added dummy values for count and % to give a better idea of what I want. Essentially, I want the above query adjusted so I have the above ranges and also two other rows with the count and %.

Example from above table, the query will tell me that there are 2 instances where the difference in two dates fall in the range 0-3 and hence 20% of overall count. Also, there are instances (due to errors) where the time taken can be negative (ie date reported is actually later than date received) so that's why I have added that "less than 0 range".

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the results in a single row (rather than two) using conditional aggregation:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select sum(case when time_spent < 0 then 1 else 0 end) as days_lt_0,
       sum(case when time_spent between 0 and 3 then 1 else 0 end) as days_0_3,
       sum(case when time_spent 4 then 1 else 0 end) as days_4,
       sum(case when time_spent 5 then 1 else 0 end) as days_5,
       sum(case when time_spent between 6 and 8 then 1 else 0 end) as days_6_38,
       sum(case when time_spent >= 9 then 1 else 0 end) as days_9pl,
       avg(case when time_spent < 0 then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_lt_0,
       avg(case when time_spent between 0 and 3 then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_0_3,
       avg(case when time_spent 4 then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_4,
       avg(case when time_spent 5 then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_5,
       avg(case when time_spent between 6 and 8 then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_6_38,
       avg(case when time_spent >= 9 then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_9pl
from t;
```

Comment: That's amazing, works like a treat. Any way I can get the % as a row rather than a column- above query gives it as a column

Comment: Also, how do i get it as if it like the table above with 3 rows (time_take, count, %). I would like it in that format if possible- currently it is just one row long

Comment: @TarikulIslam . . . That structure is not a particularly good example of a relational table, because the columns have different types.  That is why this version has the values spread across different columns.